# Adding edges to the mesh by python in specific region

Tags: modeling, python, cloth-simulation

I have a body pattern for clothing.
In order to sew two patterns which are front and back, I have to add edges to them at the very outside of mesh like pictures below.

[image] [image]

As you can see, left picture is the original patterns, and I need to add edges to the both front and back like the picture right.

The area which would be added for edges is the picture below orange parts.

[image]

The coordination of the front and back is exactly same but neck part. However, neck part would not be added any edges, so it can be ignored.

Is there any way to add edges to those area automatically by python script?

or, any other easier way than add them by manually.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Hi. The 'blender-internal-render-engine' tag relates to the Blender Internal render engine (present in blender 2.79 and removed in 2.8). I'm not sure adding a render engine tag is relevant for your question, but if you're using 2.8, then it's definitely not.

Comment: Use **bridge edge loops**

Comment: @susu Thank you very much, but what I need is that, not making face, but all edges. For example, if there are 2 lines and each line has 5 points. As I connect them, 5 edges should be created. However, Bridge edge loops makes one face or 5 faces between two lines.

Comment: You might be dealing with disconnected or duplicated vertices. Please upload a file for users to download and add it to your question.